# Question about Fibers $X_y$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

I have some questions about the proof of 5.3.17 in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry" (page 201):

[image]

Hypotheses of Thm. 3.15:
[image]

1. Why is $B = A[T] / (P(T))$ a flat A-module? That's clear that $A[T]$ should be as a free A-module flat, but I'm not sure if flatness is stable under quotient structure.
2. That's not clear how the Prop. 3.1.24 provides the isomorphism $O_{Spec B} \cong q_* O_{X_B}$.
   Here the statement of 3.1.24:

[image]

3. Why is fiber of $q$ over a closed point of $Spec B$ isomorphical to $X_y \times_{Spec k(y)} Spec E$?

Comment: Tipps: 1. Flatness is stable under base change.

Comment: 2. $\mathcal O _X (X) \cong$ (finite ext of k) as X is projective. 3. I think this is just badly worded. But this should just be "calculation".

Comment: Ad 1.: You mean $B \cong A[X]\otimes_A (k(y)[T]/ (\tilde{P}(T)))$? Ad 2.: I don't understand how utilise your isomorphism...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that $A[T]/(P(T))$ is a free module and hence flat. Just check using the fact that $P$ is monic and irreducible. Note that $P$ is irreducible since $\tilde{P}$ is irreducible.
2. Apply the flat base change theorem for the cartesian diagram

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X \times_Y Spec(B) @>{g}>> X\\
@V{q}VV @V{f}VV \\
Spec(B) @>{h}>> Spec(A)
\end{CD}
$

to get $h^*f_* \mathcal{O}_{X} \cong q_*g^*\mathcal{O}_X \cong q_*\mathcal{O}_{X_B}$ also note that you have been given $f_*\mathcal{O}_X \cong \mathcal{O}_{Spec(A)}$. Now plug this in the left hand side of the isomorphism above to get the desired isomorphism. Note that one should check that this is same as the isomorphism mentioned in proposition 1.24 as there is a lot of maps coming into picture.

3. The fiber of $q$ over a closed point in $Spec(B)$ is given by the fiber diagram

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X' @>{}>> X \times_Y Spec(B) @>{g}>> X\\
@VVV @V{q}VV @V{f}VV \\
Spec(E) @>>> Spec(B) @>{h}>> Spec(A)
\end{CD}
$

The outer square is cartesian. Note that the bottom arrow is composition of two morphism $Spec(E) \rightarrow Spec(k(y)) \rightarrow Spec(A)$. Then consider the following

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_y \times_{Spec(k(y))} Spec(E) @>{}>> X_y @>{g}>> X\\
@VVV @VVV @V{f}VV \\
Spec(E) @>>> Spec(k(y)) @>{h}>> Spec(A)
\end{CD}
$

This is a diagram with both the squares cartesian and hence the the whole big square is cartesian. Note that the bottom map in the two big squares in the diagrams under section 3 is same and hence the fiber product must be the same(universal property of fiber diagrams). Hence fiber of $q$ over the closed point that is $X'$ is nothing but $X_y \times_{Spec(k(y))} Spec(E)$.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the detailed answer. I have two questions about your argumentation steps: First(ad 2.): Which induced morphisms of schemes do you mean with $h^*, g^* $ therefore with UPPER star? And the secound one(ad 3.): In general the fiber of a point of q over a (closed) point $p \in SpecB$ is defined as $X_B \times _{Spec B} Spec \ \bar{k}(p)$ where $\bar{k}(p)$ is the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_{Spec B, p}$. According your explanations we have $X' =X_B \times _{Spec B} Spec E $, so we should have $E = \bar{k}(p)$, right? But why this equation holds?

Comment: 2. They are the morphisms as sheaves of modules. Upper star denotes pullback(and not just inverse image) of a sheaf of module.

Comment: 3. Because that is the only closed point of the ring $B$. Note that $B$ is a finite integral extension of $A$ and hence maximal ideals of $B$ contract to maximal ideals of $A$. There is only one maximal ideal of $A$ say $\matfrak{m}$. Hence the maximal ideal of B is same as maximal ideal of B containing $\matfrak{m}$, that is they are inverse image of maximal ideals in $B/ \maatfrak{m} B$. But this is a field. Hence $\matfrak{m}B$ is the maximal ideal of $B$.